Distance between distributions of a Markov chain and its perturbation.
I'm considering the following questions: Given a finite-state Markov chain and an initial distribution $\mu_0$. After $n$ steps, we can get a distribution of $X_n$. Now we give a perturbation of its transition matrix (we will guarantee that the perturbation is also a transition matrix). We still use $\mu_0$ as the initial distribution. After $n$ steps, we get a distribution of $X'_n$. Now we want to bound the distance of distributions between $X_n$ and $X_n'$.
I try to directly estimate the error between $P^n$ and $\tilde{P}^n$. But I cannot get a certain bound. This method actually does not use the condition that both $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ are transiton matrix.
I think this question should have been studied. Can anyone give some ideas or some references?
